# Formatting programatically added controls to fit in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a program in Visual Basic through Microsoft Excel, where I can input all the information from an application into excel. Each row is unique and features a dropdown control that is created and placed programatically (see code below).

The problem I have come across is correctly placing the control in each cell within one of the columns.

I have read through documents on the web and seen examples on other questions but none of them seem to work for my situation. I keep having to guess-n-check the x and y values for the AddFormControl function to place the controls in a somewhat correct way.

Code:

```
For y = 1 To UBound(array) + 1

   Set lb = Sheet1.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, 274, 32 + (19 * y), 77, 19)
   With lb
       .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3
       .ControlFormat.AddItem "Select a value", 1
       .ControlFormat.AddItem "Auto", 2
       .ControlFormat.AddItem "Default", 3
       .ControlFormat.Value = 1
   End With

Next y
```

I have counted the width's and height's of all the rows and columns so that I can place the controls in the correct spot but they are offset, some more than others.

The 274 x-value above is what lines up to the spot I would like it to for the x-axis on the excel sheet but is not how wide the columns prior to the spot add up to. Same goes for the y-value 77.

What would be the most efficient solution to this issue?

Comment: You can use (eg) `Range("C5").Top` for positioning (also .Left, .Width, .Height)

Comment: @TimWilliams This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `Range.Top` and `Range.Left` to place your From Controls exactly where you want them and they will be perfectly lined up with the cell in question. This is a great method for adding them in large quantities dynamically.